# Extracting `dll` files from the Resources after they been added using CodeDOM in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dll, resources, codedom

**I'v seen a lot of answers here on `stackoverflow`**, but none of them help me with exactly what i need and almost all of them in C# when i need VB, so i hope someone will help me with my problem, which is this :

I have compiled a `exe` file in vb.net using `CodeDOM`, and i added two `dll` file to its resources and that worked just fine and you can even notice that the size of the `exe` has increase after adding the resources, but when i run the `exe` file like that `My.Resources.Touchless`, it gives me an error saying that

> "Resources" is not a member of "My".

And what i need is to read these `dll` files from the compiled `exe` file and then extract them using `File.WriteAllBytes()...`, **if i didn't try to extract the files from the resources and instead of that i copied them manually to the executable path,  the application will work perfectly, so the problem is just with trying to call the `dll` files from the resources.**

Here is some code :

```
Public Shared Function Compile(ByVal Output As String, ByVal Source As String, ByVal Icon As String, ByVal resources As String) As Boolean
    Dim Parameters As New CompilerParameters()
    Dim cResults As CompilerResults = Nothing

    Dim Compiler As CodeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")
    Parameters.GenerateExecutable = True
    Parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = False
    Parameters.OutputAssembly = Output
    Parameters.MainClass = "MyNamespace.MainWindow"
    Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(Path.GetTempPath & "TouchlessLib.dll")
    Parameters.EmbeddedResources.Add(Path.GetTempPath & "WebCamLib.dll")
    Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(New String() {"System.dll", "System.Drawing.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll", "System.Management.dll", Path.GetTempPath & "TouchlessLib.dll"})
    Parameters.CompilerOptions = "/platform:x86 /target:winexe"
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Icon) Then
        File.Copy(Icon, "icon.ico")
        Parameters.CompilerOptions += " /win32icon:" & "icon.ico"
    End If
    cResults = Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Parameters, Source)
    If cResults.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For Each compile_error As CompilerError In cResults.Errors
            Dim [error] As CompilerError = compile_error
            Console.Beep()
            MsgBox("Error: " & [error].ErrorText & vbCr & vbLf & [error].Line)
        Next
        Return False
    End If
    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Icon)) Then
        File.Delete("icon.ico")
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

When i call them from the compiled `exe` file like this :

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\TouchlessLib.dll", My.Resources.TouchlessLib)
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\WebCamLib.dll", My.Resources.WebCamLib)
```

... i get the following error message :

> "Resources" is not a member of "My".

Comment: Don't know if this'll work, but try: `MyApplication.Resources`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: @VisualVincent I can add this `CodeDOM` compiled `exe` file to the resources of a normal `exe` file compiled with VB IDE plus the `dll` files and extract them in the same place, and it will work, but this is  not very smooth i think!

Comment: Have your tried `MyNamespace.My.Resources` And can you show the code on how how exactly your are trying to access the files.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and help, i think i'm gonna stick with my old way...

Answer (score 0):

The `My` namespace and any associated functionality is created via auto-generated code.  Since your code is now the code generator and not the IDE, you will not have those niceties unless your code provides it.

To extract an embedded resource, you need to include code similar to the following in the source code you are compiling with CodeDOM.

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim resouceNames As String() = asm.GetManifestResourceNames
For Each s As String In resouceNames
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(s)
    Using strm As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(s)
        Using fs As Stream = fi.Create()
            strm.CopyTo(fs)
        End Using
    End Using
Next
```

Make sure that you also include:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.IO
```

This code retrieves the executing `Assembly` obtains an array of embedded resource names.  It then calls [GetManifestResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the named resource as a stream. This stream is copied to a file stream.

Modify the example to suite your needs.

Note that I have not included any error checking/handling in this example.  Anything dealing with IO should have some error handling.

Edit:
Based on the comment below, it appears that only a copy/paste type answer will do for the OP.

```
Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Dim resourceName As String
Dim fi As FileInfo
resourceName = "TouchlessLib.dll"
fi = New FileInfo(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, resourceName))
Using strm As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)
    Using fs As Stream = fi.Create()
        strm.CopyTo(fs)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, that does not have any compiling issues, but how do i extract the files. i used : File.Create(Application.ExecutablePath & "TouchlessLib.dll", fs.ReadByte())..., but that didn't work, can you help with that?

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily, see my edit.  Also, what do you think `Application.ExecutablePath & "TouchlessLib.dll"` produces?

Comment: Thanks. `Application.ExecutablePath & "\TouchlessLib.dll"` will produce a string for the path of where i started the `exe` file `+` the name of the resource that i want to extract to that path.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this class:

```
Imports System.Dynamic
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class DynamicResources
    Inherits DynamicObject
    Public Overrides Function TryGetMember(binder As GetMemberBinder, ByRef result As Object) As Boolean

        Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        Dim resouceNames As String() = asm.GetManifestResourceNames
        For Each s As String In resouceNames
            Dim name As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)
            Dim Manager As New Resources.ResourceManager(name, asm)
            Try
                Dim resource = Manager.GetObject(binder.Name)
                If Not resource Is Nothing Then
                    result = resource
                    Return True
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        Next
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

You can use it like this:

```
 Dim root as string=Application.StartupPath
 File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(root, "TouchlessLib.dll"), DynamicResources.TouchlessLib)
 File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(root, "WebCamLib.dll"), DynamicResources.WebCamLib)
```

Comment: Unfortunately when i try to compile it gives me this error message : [http://imgur.com/a/PLobj](http://imgur.com/a/PLobj)

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Core.dll`

Comment: We got rid of that one, but we're getting now a new error message : [http://imgur.com/a/w8E7i](http://imgur.com/a/w8E7i)

Comment: Type: `DynamicResources` not `DynamiceResources`

Comment: Right, but now it says that `"TouchlessLib" is not a member of "DynamicResources"` and that is when trying to extract them using `File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(root, "TouchlessLib.dll"), DynamicResources.TouchlessLib)` .